# Highlight the duplicate in pair

Tags: spreadsheet, highlight, countif

I try to make colume A to check if there is duplicate, but I do need to have a total in A1, 
since A1 will have the number that can be equal to the data that fill in A5 and below,
if I change the conditional format from

```
=countif(A:A,A5)>1 to
=countif(A5:A100,A5)>1
```

it will only highlight 1 cell only, how can I make it similar to Excel that will highlight the pair?

```
1       set time    14:00


Scan below      Time In Late
1   1   14:09:25    0:09
2   2   16:10:10    2:10
3   3   14:09:53    0:09
    4   16:21:26    2:21
9   5   16:20:15    2:20
15  4   16:10:17    2:10
        16:21:29    2:21
10      14:44:16    0:44
11      14:44:18    0:44
23      14:44:20    0:44
34      14:44:24    0:44
15      16:38:50    2:38
```

[Spreadsheet in Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AwG9yjs9jCUf8NgJcOyee3tL7hiDoagUXH54CHREAiA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this amended custom formula:

`=countif(A$5:A,A5)>1`